# Convert string in Array into number then adding them all up to get the total in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I was able to "add" up all the string numbers but since they are string they just appear in the console side-by-side and obviously I can't actually add them up. How do I go about making them a number within my existing code?

```
let myStuff = [
  {
   "my_game":"PS4",
   "worth":"25.30"
  },
  {
   "my_cards":"pokemon",
   "worth":"10.50"
  },
]

const totalProfit = myStuff.reduce((cTotal, stuff) => {
   return stuff.worth + cTotal
}, 0);

console.log(totalProfit)
```

I just get this:
**25.3010.50** but it should add all of the worth which would equate to **35.80**

Tried looking around and tried .map(Number) to convert it but nothing works.

Comment: Convert ``worth``: ``return +stuff.worth + cTotal``

Comment: Type casting is a very basic concept in programing, you should check out data types first.